# Invalid Index when using for_each in terraform

Tags: for-loop, indexing, foreach, terraform

I have the following terraform module which is essentially creating s3 buckets. I keep seem to be having an issue with s3_replication_rules. I am not sure whether the data structure that I have in my tfvars is incorrect or there is something wrong with the way I am obtaining the values within my s3_custom_module. I have been battling with this for a few hours and no luck. Any help would be much appreciated. I am using the third-party module from cloudpose : https://registry.terraform.io/modules/cloudposse/s3-bucket/aws/3.0.0. I can see the input s3_replication_rules is **list(any)**. Do I have the incorrect data structure in my tfvars ?

My s3 module code is as follows :

```
module "s3_custom_module" {
  for_each                       = var.s3_custom_buckets
  source                         = "../../modules/s3_module"
  bucket_name                    = each.value["name"]
  versioning_enabled             = each.value["versioning_enabled"]
  project                        = var.project
  environment                    = var.environment
  component                      = var.component
  default_tags                   = local.default_tags
  lifecycle_configuration_rules  = local.lifecycle_configuration_rules
  sns_key                        = data.terraform_remote_state.security.outputs.sns_key
  http_success_feedback_role_arn = local.sns_iam_role_arn
  http_failure_feedback_role_arn = local.sns_iam_role_arn
  s3_replication_enabled         = each.value["s3_replication_enabled"]
  s3_replication_rules = each.value["s3_replication_enabled"] ? [
    {
      id                 = each.value["s3_replication_rules"][0].id
      status             = each.value["s3_replication_rules"][0].status
      prefix             = each.value["s3_replication_rules"][0].prefix
      priority           = each.value["s3_replication_rules"][0].priority
      destination_bucket = data.terraform_remote_state.s3_buckets.outputs.map_s3_bucket_arn.s3_published_backup_bucket
      destination = {
        account_id = var.aws_account_id
        metrics = {
          status = null
        }
      }
    }
  ] : null
```

}

var.s3_custom_buckets is references as part of my tfvars as follows :

```
s3_custom_buckets = {
 s3_external_bucket = {
    name                   = "ddap-dev-data-s3-external-bucket",
    versioning_enabled     = false
    s3_replication_enabled = false
    s3_replication_rules   = []
    logging_enabled        = true
  },
s3_replication_bucket = {
    name                    = "ddap-dev-s3-replication-bucket"
    versioning_enabled      = true
    s3_replication_enabled  = true
    s3_replication_rules = [
      {
        id                 = "replication-ddap-dev-data-s3-published-bucket"
        status             = "Enabled"
        prefix             = "/extra"
        priority           = 5
        destination_bucket = "ddap-dev-s3-replication-bucket"
      }
    ]
    source_policy_documents = [] #todo we need to add policy
    logging_enabled         = true
  }
```

I have the following in variables.tf :

```
variable "s3_custom_buckets" {
  type = map(object({
    name                   = string
    versioning_enabled     = bool
    s3_replication_enabled = bool
    logging_enabled        = bool
  }))
  description = "List of maps to generate custom S3 buckets"
}
```

I keep seeing this error when I  run a terraform plan :

**

```
Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on module_s3_custom.tf line 19, in module "s3_custom_module":
│   19:       status             = each.value["s3_replication_rules"][0].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 4 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on module_s3_custom.tf line 20, in module "s3_custom_module":
│   20:       prefix             = each.value["s3_replication_rules"][0].status
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 4 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on module_s3_custom.tf line 21, in module "s3_custom_module":
│   21:       priority           = each.value["s3_replication_rules"][0].prefix
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 4 attributes

│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

 Error: Invalid index
│ 
│   on module_s3_custom.tf line 21, in module "s3_custom_module":
│   21:       priority           = each.value["s3_replication_rules"][0].priority
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value is object with 4 attributes
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.

╵
ERROR: Terraform plan failed**
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the following in my variables declaration :

```
  s3_replication_rules   = list(map(any))
```

So final variable now looks like the following :

```
variable "s3_custom_buckets" {
  type = map(object({
    name                   = string
    versioning_enabled     = bool
    s3_replication_enabled = bool
    s3_replication_rules   = list(map(any))
    logging_enabled        = bool
  }))
  description = "List of maps to generate custom S3 buckets"
}
```